# Получаю 401 при вызове API c Bearer токеном

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

При входе я получаю токен. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при вызове API с токеном получаю 401 ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делал аналогично с ресурса: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-2/

Comment: Для кого сделали вкладку `Authorization` в программе? эх.

Comment: Не понял, можете по подробнее обьяснить?